# use ref to remove html node?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

how to avoid using state but use ref to remove html element?

```
export default function App() {
  const divRef = useRef();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div ref={divRef}>
        <div
          onClick={() => {
            console.log(divRef.current);
          }}
        >
          click to remove this node
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

removeChildren don't exist on current?

Comment: Why not just use `e.target.remove()` in the `onClick` handler (you need to pass `e` as an argument obviously)?

Answer (score 0):

`divRef.current.removeChild`, not `removeChildren`

```
<div
  onClick={() => {
    console.log(divRef.current);
    divRef.current.removeChild(divRef.current.children[0])
  }}
>
```

Comment: Not is it enough like this? `divRef.current.remove();`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, This HTML Element can be remove without using UseState Hook.

```js
import { useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {
  // Init UseRef Hook
  const divElement = useRef();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div ref={divElement}>
        <div
          onClick={() => {
            divElement.current.remove();
          }}
        >
          click to remove this node
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Using the OnClick, we are removing the `divElement` from the useRef.

[Here is the Sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/blazing-river-0q6fb6?file=/src/App.js:0-349)